# nodejs or golang client can not access mongodb, however, mongsh can connect and read with same auth setting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, go, master-slave

I develop an app which working well on reading and writing data to remote mongodb, recently, we change to another remote mongodb instance with master-slave setting, however, encounter the following strange issue.

**Mongshell** can connect and read mongodb with auth of user/pwd, **however, nodejs or golang client** can not access it with the same auth, the following pic is the error info **"Server selection timed out after 30000 ms"**,

[image]

I tried this solution to **add parameter "?directConnection=true"** to connection string, this time, nodejs or golang can connect the mongodb, however, **can not read**, with the following error **"not primary and secondaryOk=false"**,

[image]

BTW, I also tried other solutions, but not working, such as, add parameter "readPreference=primaryPreferred" to connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by adding parameter suffix "?readPreference=secondary&directConnection=true" to connection string, so the connection string look like,

```js
"mongodb://name:passwd@ip:port?readPreference=secondary&directConnection=true"
```

Comment: It's worked for me, after adding the flag `readPreference=secondary` in the database connection.

Thanks @Xing Chang